# Tell me the way to define tablerow was clicked

Tags: android, onclick, tablerow

I have this code to create table layout. In every row, had one OnclickListener event.

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        TextView title1 = new TextView(this);
        title1.setText("Thành Phố:"+i);

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        params.span = 5;

        TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
        rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        rowTitle.addView(title1, params);             
        TableRow tbr2 = new TableRow(this);
        **tbr2.setOnClickListener(onclick);**        
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);          
        tv2.setText("type"+i);          
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText("buy"+i);           
        tbr2.addView(tv3);       
        tbr2.addView(tv2);        
        table.addView(rowTitle);
        table.addView(tbr2);        
    }
    scr.addView(table);
    layout.addView(scr);
    setContentView(layout);
```

and this is Onclicklistener

```
 private OnClickListener onclick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("1234", "abcd");
    }
};
```

and this is my proplem: everyrow i must do another work. Please tell me how to check table row was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Outside loop
int[] ids = {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5}; // or int[] ids = {R.id.table_row_1 // etc };

// Inside loop

TableRow tbr2 = new TableRow(this);
tbr2.setId(ids[i]);
tbr2.setOnClickListener(onclick); 


// On Click
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
           case 1: // or R.id.table_row_1
               // tbr2
             break;
        }
    }
```

sup? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Blundell's solution is perfectly acceptable. If you don't want to do that, another approach is use a different OnClickListener for each row.

```
private OnClickListener[] clickListeners = new OnClickListener[] { 
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("0", "Row 0 click");
        }
    },       
    new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("1", "Row 1 click");
        }
    }, 
    //Continue with more click listeners
};
```

Your code to set the listeners than becomes

```
tbr2.setOnClickListener(clickListeners[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) on each table row, storing some identifying object (e.g. its row number). Set the same `onclick` for every row. In `onClick()` use `v.getTag()` to get your row number (or whatever).

E.g. (untested):

```
tbr2.setTag(i);
```

then...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("1234", String.format("row %d", v.getTag()));
}
```

Comment: Why use setTag when setId is designed for this exact scenario. Your just going to confuse someone who has to maintain your code.

Comment: Because an integer is only one of the things you could usefully store. An object storing all of that row's data fields might actually be more useful here, which is why I said "some identifying object". But, yes, setId() would work if you only wanted to store an int.